# What is the name of this Hebrew pronunciation at 0:58?

Tags: pronunciation, hebrew

The pronunciation is guttural but at the same time the pronunciation is the kind of pronunciation that Classical Latin and the Romance languages have! For example, the pronunciation of the Classical Latin word lacrimōsa!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7ONKae3pjg

http://www.stilus.nl/horatius/HorCarI-8LydiaDicPerOmnes.htm The pronunciation of the Classical Latin word lacrimōsa is by Thomas Bervoets!

Comment: What do you mean by "pronunciation" here? The particular sounds being spoken? The intonation and prosody? Something else?

Comment: The particular sounds being spoken!

Comment: At 0:58 in the Hebrew song, a very clear velar fricative [x] is pronounced. The sound in _lacrimōsa_ in the recording by Thomas Bervoets is an alveolar trill (as in your previous two questions!). They are not the same sound, and they don’t sound anything like each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At 0:58 in the video, the Hebrew lyrics being sung go:

> הקור גובר, אך יש חום בלב
> *hakór govér, akh yesh khom balév*
> "the cold is increasing, but there's warmth in the heart"

The 0:58 second mark hits in the middle of the word גובר *govér*, so immediately after the number changes you'll hear the end of that word containing a vowel and a uvular approximant, something like [-eːʁ̞].

Soon after, in the words אך *akh* and חום *khom* you'll hear two voiceless uvular fricatives [χ] – or the latter may be a velar rather than a uvular fricative, as noted by Janus above – both before the counter changes to 0:59. That's some fast singing there :)

The pronunciation of the ⟨r⟩ in *lacrimōsa* is **supposed** to be an alveolar trill, but it really doesn't sound terribly much like one to me. The recording has plenty of alveolar trills in other places, and there's a marked difference between the ⟨r⟩ of *lacrimōsa* and that of the following *Trōiae*. It's articulated much less forcefully, for sure, and I might entertain the idea that the declaimer, being Dutch, is letting his native uvular /r/ sound intrude into the declamation.